# C++ Loan Qualifying Amount

Tags: c++, finance

I cannot figure out the logical equation/math on how to figure out what amount a person would qualify at for a loan and the number of years it would take.  The text in bold below is where I'm stuck.  Any ideas would be appreciated, including formula suggestions.

Complete program specification:

Inputting the customer’s annual income, number of years of the loan (loan period), the amount of the loan (the loan amount), and the customer’s status (P for Preferred or R for Regular). Approve the loan if the customer meets either of the following conditions. For a Regular customer - the loan amount divided by the number of months in the loan period <= to10% of the customer’s monthly income. Or, if the customer is a preferred customer, the loan amount divided by the number of months in the loan period <= 1% of the customer’s annual income. Output approval or disapproval.

***What I can't figure out:***

If the loan is disapproved (2) **tell the customer the maximum amount the loan could be based on current income** (3) **how long the period (round up to the nearest whole year) would have to be to approve the loan at the current income**.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

double income, preferred_validation, regular_validation, years, loan_amount, monthlyIncome, annualIncomeTest, max_amount, request_amount;
char status;

cout<<"Please enter the annual income of the customer: ";
cin>>income;

cout<<"\nPlease enter the number of years of the loan: ";
cin>>years;

cout<<"\nPlease enter the amount of the loan: ";
cin>>loan_amount;

cout<<"\nCustomer status: P - Preferred R - Regular."<<endl;

cout<<"Please enter the customer's status: ";
cin>>status;

if(status != 'P' || 'R')
{
    status='R';

    cout<<"\n\nThe customer status code you input does not match one of the choices.\nThe calculations that follow are based on the applicant being a Regular customer."<<endl;
}


if(status=='R')
{


regular_validation=loan_amount/(years*12);
monthlyIncome=((income/12)*.10);


if(regular_validation<=monthlyIncome)
{
    cout<<"\nThis loan is approved.";
}
else
{
    cout<<"\nThis loan is disapproved.";
}

}
else if(status=='P')
{

    preferred_validation=loan_amount/(years*12);
    annualIncomeTest=income*.01;

    if(preferred_validation<=annualIncomeTest)
    {
        cout<<"\nThis loan is approved.";
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"\nThis loan is disapproved."<<endl;

        max_amount=???;

        cout<<"As a preferred customer, the largest loan you qualify for is "<<max_amount<<" or you can get the requested amount of "<<loan_amount<<" by increasing the loan period to "<<years<<" years.";
    }

}
else
{
    cout<<"Restart and enter your customer status.";
}






cin.get();
cin.get();

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(status != 'P' || 'R')
```

Should be:

```
if(status != 'P' && status != 'R')
```

Obviously you reject the loan when `preferred_validation <=`annualIncomeTest`, then max_amount should be annualIncomeTest?

```
max_amount= annualIncomeTest;
```